# Does Light Intensity Depend on Area

Tags: electromagnetism

I have heard that by increasing the slit size in a diffraction experiment, the intensity of light at the slit changes. However, I have also been told that intensity equals power per unit area in which case I would think that changing the slit size would not change the intensity since the power and the area are changing. So what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

This would be true if [Fraunhofer diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction) didn't exist (i.e. if only geometric optics was valid). When you send a beam through a small slit, it disperses more widely, and hence the **Intensity** goes down. Of course, this assumes that in each case the initial intensity is the same.

[image]

Comment: But I have been told that intensity is directly proportional to the slit width. How can you prove this?

Comment: Yes, it turns out to first order approximation that the intensity at locations near the center of the beam's image does go up linearly with beam width. The bigger the width, **the closer the intensity of the image on the right-side gets to the intensity of the original beam on the right-hand side.**

Comment: I am a little confused by what you are saying. Can you cite a source?